# getting error - Type 'Any' Has no Subscript Members - swift3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

```
enter code here
@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


var sentimentURL = "https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/sync/analyzesentiment/v2?text=this+is+lethargic&apikey=e55bc0ff-70a5-4270-b464-aaaf3dfcc8de&text="
var sentimentResponse:NSDictionary!

func getSentiment() {
    var error:NSError?
    var encodedText = textfield.text.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)


    Get.JSON(url: sentimentURL+encodedText!) {
        (response) in
        self.sentimentResponse  = response

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {

            var agggregate = self.sentimentResponse["aggregate"]!["sentiment"]! as String
            self.label.text = agggregate

        }
    }
}
```

in this line 
" var agggregate = self.sentimentResponse["aggregate"]!["sentiment"]! as String" 
im getting error like Type 'Any' Has no Subscript Members.please help me in sorting this problem.thankyou in advance...

Comment: still im not getting whts the error plz help in sorting this error @ericaya

Answer (score 0):

You're using a function `Get.JSON`. You don't tell us what that is, or what data type the response will be.

I'm guessing that it is type `Any`, or perhaps `[String:Any]`.

Your code `self.sentimentResponse["aggregate"]!["sentiment"]!` fails because the compiler does not know what kind of data `self.sentimentResponse` contains.

You could try casting it to the correct type:

```
guard let typedResponse  = response as? [String: [String:String]] else {return}
self.sentimentResponse = typedResponse
guard let aggregate = typedResponse["aggregate"] else {return}
guard let sentiment = aggregate["sentiment"] else {return}
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
   self.label.text = sentiment
}
```

(In the above code I'm using 3 separate guard statements to make debugging easier. You could use one guard statement with 3 separate let statements and accomplish the same thing)

Comment: hey @duncanc tanq for replying when i run with ur code im getting this error in first line of code initilizer for conditionbinding must have optional type , not [String: [String:String]]

Comment: Sorry. In the first line, `as!` should have been `as?`

Comment: tanq very much bro now its working...

Comment: NP. You should accept my answer if it solved your problem.